# multi site not showing the header/nav on one site

Tags: javascript, css, magento, navigation

so i have a multi site setup and everything seemed to run fine until the other day when one of the sites decided to not show the header/nav

here are the two sites:
https://allholders.com/ and 
http://marketingholders.com/

i think this happened after i combined JS/css but all my other sites are fine except for my main install of magento. I've tried going back and forth between combined and not combined but it doesn't seem to make a difference....cleared all cache but still cant get allholders.com to display the top part of the site. It looks like it displays for a split second then dissapears

any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: in CSS .header is not present z-index: 4; and in header block in HTML is not present search form and style section of the search form.

Comment: There is unclosed DIV in your markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ar unclosed `divs` in Your header template and `.header-container` "eats" other tags. You should add **three** more `</div>` before `.nav-container` (I guess at the end of header template)

Comment: so even though both sites use the same header file this could still be causing a problem in one site and not the other?

Comment: probably happened on different browsers

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the missing `div`s mentioned above, the only problem I see so far is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
```

should be this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Notice the missing closing tag.

Comment: thank you for noticing that

Comment: self closing tags are not required to have / in HTML5